# dateFormatter dateFromString error only on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, date, swift2

when running following code

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"

 let a:String = "10/24/2015 12:00:00 PM"
 let b:NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(a)
```

on simulator b converts as expected to `NSDate` with correct value on Simulator
on iPhone / physical device, b is nil ...

how can I get the correct result also on physical device?? is this an IOS bug or a calendar related issue?

Comment: Change "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a" to "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a" Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of covering the bases for those using a different formatter

I would suggest using dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") . This ensures the date on users device is forced to fit your date formatter. Using locale could cause crash if user is using the 24hr format which your formatter doesn't handle.

If your formatter uses HH which is 24hr instead of h which is 12hr use 
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_GB")

Answer (score 2):

The following fixed the issue (Thank you RyanTCB):

```
 let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a"
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

 let a:String = "10/24/2015 12:00:00 PM"
 let b:NSDate? = dateFormatter.dateFromString(a)
```

Comment: Despite my answer being the one that helped you accepted your own?

Comment: Sorry Ryan. Had no idea this has any consequence

Answer (score 0):

Set locale on your date formatter:

```
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
```

Comment: I would suggest using dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US") . This ensures the date on users device is forced to fit your date formatter. Using locale could cause crash if user is using the 24hr format which your formatter doesn't handle.

Comment: Glad it helped. Thank @RyanTCB as well!. Could you please accept this answer for the benefit of others.